# What is the word that means to assign a probability?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, the word that means to assign a price is "price," so I can say that I priced something. I can't find the word that means to assign a probability, so for example, what is the correct way to say "I probability-ized something?"

Comment: 'I can't find the word [for] ...' often means that the enquirer isn't aware that lexical gaps occur in English.

Comment: Why do you think such a verb exists or is even needed? There are infinitely many combinations of ᴠᴇʀʙ+ᴏʙᴊᴇᴄᴛ lacking succinct single-word synonyms that cover both in one verb the way *rank* works for *assign priorities* or *order by something*. Of course one can always derive new verbs by applying standard noun-to-verb derivational morphology, and indeed the OED attests both *probabilize* and *probabilify* as verbs, but such unsightly behemoths are best left untapped.  If you can't use *rank* I recommend using actual language to construct a phrase that has the meaning you want, not monsters.

Comment: What is the word that means to assign a height? What is the word that means to assign a density? What is the word that means to assign a car? What is the word that means to assign scissors? What is the word that means to assign a ghostbuster? What is the word that means to assign a pie? And what is the word for not understanding how language works?

Comment: This isn't a single word, but if you need some variety, you could *calculate the odds* or *determine the likelihood*. // By the way, "to price something" often means to check what the common prices for the item are.  "To price something at a certain value" would fit more with what you were saying.

Comment: I voted to re-open because actually OP did show how it would be used: "I probability-ized something."

Comment: @aparente001 That is only one of the criteria for SWRs. There are more –
 see the [tag:single-word-requests] tag wiki.

Comment: @MetaEd - I was going by the close reason I read here.

Comment: @aparente001 Understood. "Information on how it will be used" is actually intended to mean not just giving a sample sentence but actually providing all the information on how it will be used that's called for by the linked tag wiki, including research results, part of speech, register, acceptance criteria, etc. In fact, if you see a way to improve on how that close reason is written, you might throw a suggestion onto meta. The mod team can and occasionally does edit the close reasons.

Comment: You can ask about the way a concept is phrased in English, regardless of whether the phrasing exists in English - you're not expected to know the answer before posting the question. However, you need to describe what you have in mind. Are you talking about betting on horse-racing (to describe what bookmakers do), random-number generation (to describe initialising the probability distribution), something about quantitative analysis (to describe the statistical underpinnings of the insurance industry), or something else? Add a paragraph to your question to describe the scenario you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Though not a single word, you could use the phrase ***to set the odds*** (intransitive) or ***to set the odds of [something]*** (transitive).

From [Wikipedia article on Odds Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_compiler):

> An odds compiler (or trader) is a person employed by a bookmaker or
>   betting exchange who ***sets the odds for*** events (such as sporting
>   outcomes) for customers to place bets on.

---

**EDIT:**  This is not a good answer...see @Edwin Ashworth's convincing comments below.  Seems the best answer is "assign probabilities."

Comment: Though related, probabilities and odds set by eg a bookmaker are different.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, if this is a case of a lexical gap as you intimate, what is the solution for communication?

Comment: Using the phrase in your question, rather than a single word.

Comment: OP has already given this: _assign a probability_. This may be on the basis of symmetry {p(H) = 50% for the result of the toss of a _fair_ (!) coin; p (a _5_) = 1/6 for a throw of a 'fair' dice} or estimated on the basis of previous outcomes. Setting odds takes into account further factors (trying to make a profit / encouraging the backing of outsiders / discouraging the backing of the favourites ...).